# Cat D11 Bulldozer (42131) set's calibration always reset

Tags: technic

Calibration of my Cat D11 Bulldozer went without any issues. Everything worked fine. The problem came after. When I disconnect, either by Bluetooth or manually, the calibration data went out the window and all the functions don't work properly anymore. So I have to calibrate again. Sometimes, when calibration get stuck at the blade, I have to remove the app and download it again, to get a good calibration again. But when I disconnect the hub again I can start all over again. Anybody knows how to solve this?